# Syncing project settings and FTP info in PHPStorm with VCS?

Tags: phpstorm

I work on multiple computers with different operating systems. One of the IDEs I use a lot is PHPStorm and I am looking for a nice solution to sync all of the files and all of the settings for the project. I am assuming that the project specific settings are in the .idea folder however the ftp settings are stored elsewhere.

What is the best way to sync ftp settings between multiple computers? Can this be done easily via VCS or is there another better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File | Export Settings...` and then `File | Import Settings...` for manual sync.

The ordinary file sync (via any software) will do as long as it's the same OS/platform and all computers have similar folder structure (in terms of used tools, projects locations etc) -- that's mainly for settings that include references to 3rd party tools or list of recent projects etc. General settings (non path related) like "Live Templates" or "Color scheme" can easily be synced.

**IntelliJ Configuration Server Plugin** is definitely worth checking out -- http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4560?pr=phpStorm

---

As for project settings -- they are VCS-safe. Excluding `workspace.xml`, which is intended for use on that computer/user. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems